# Oracle SQL: Hierarchical WHERE ... IN

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a select-statement, where I finder on a certain field

```
select * from table t
where t.field in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

I would like to subset in such as way that it should return a given row if the column has the value `val1`, otherwise it should return the row with value `val2` and finally the row with `val3`. So an ordered where-clause so to speak. Is that possible somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the `val1` rows and, then if none exist, get all the `val2` rows and then, if none exist, all the `val3` rows then, from Oracle 12, you can use `ORDER BY` and `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
ORDER BY field
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

If your priorities are not in ascending order then use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
ORDER BY
       CASE field
       WHEN 'val1' THEN 1
       WHEN 'val2' THEN 2
       WHEN 'val3' THEN 3
       END
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

In earlier versions, you can use the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         RANK() OVER (
           ORDER BY CASE field
                    WHEN 'val1' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'val2' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'val3' THEN 3
                    END
         ) AS rnk
  FROM   table t
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

seems COALESCE function might help you
https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rreffunccoalesce.html

Comment: `coalesce` checks for `nullability` which's not the OP wants to be checked.

Comment: Thanks, but @BarbarosÖzhan is right - I want to select rows based on a hierarchy